# Where did this "+1" term come from for this inductive proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-verification

Where did this "+1" term come from for this inductive proof? It is in boxed in black.

[image]

For context,

We are trying to prove this sequence:

[image]

has the following solution:

$$x_{ n }=\frac { 3^{ n+1 }-3-2n }{ 4 }$$

Comment: Good observation! +1.

Comment: The problem is not in the box but in the line before. There is an unfortunate mistake: $x_{k+1}=3x_k+k+1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote that $x_n$ is defined as $x_1=1$ and $x_k=3x_{k-1}+k$ for $k\geq2$.
Hence the error is NOT the "$+1$" in the point you indicated: the mistake is when you write:
$$
x_{k+1}=3x_k+k
$$
in fact, according to definition, you here missed a "$+1$": $x_k=3x_{k-1}+k\Longrightarrow x_{k+1}=3x_k+(k+1)$.
After this everything should be fixed.